# Count + Distinct SQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a research table like

```
researcher    award

 person1      award1
 person1      award2
 person2      award3
```

What I want to get is to count the award based on researcher but it researcher shouldnt be
repeated. So in this example. The result should be

```
 2
```

Coz award1 and award2 is the same person + award3 which is a different person.

I already tried

```
SELECT count(award) from research where researcher=(select distinct(researcher) from researcher)
```

But it says

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

So any alternative solution or changes?

Comment: `SELECT researcher, count(award) FROM research GROUP BY researcher`?

Comment: Are you trying to count the people or the awards? In other words, is the result "2" because person 1 has 2 awards, or because there are 2 people that have awards?

Comment: Yes, because the 2 people have awards.

Comment: This question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(*) from (select researcher, count(*) 
from MyTable
group by researcher) as tempTable;
```

Comment: why is that there is 'as cnt'? can't we just erase it? I tried erasing 'as tempTable' but it says subquery should have a name.

Comment: And oh yes, where can I put 'where award is not null'?

Comment: This query makes no sense

Comment: removed as cnt since there is no need.

Comment: @Hogan this exactly returns what the OP requested. It returns the number of awards without double counting the researchers. It counts the rows of the group by query...

Comment: @Saher - ok... I totally miss-read the question, but this does not check if award is null

Answer (score 2):

This will give you researcher and count

```
select researcher, count(*) as c
from table
group by researcher
```

maybe you only want awarded ones?

```
select researcher, count(*) as c
from table
where award is not null
group by researcher
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a group by and count the distinct award.

```
SELECT count(distinct award) from research group by researcher
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT    COUNT( DISTINCT Award ) AS awardCount 

FROM      Research 

GROUP BY  Researcher
```